# Reference for Gauss-Green formula with $C^1$ boundary

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, stokes-theorem

I am reading Evans's appendix, which includes the following Gauss-Green formula,[image]

In the setting of Riemannian manifolds, we can consider divergence etc. and we have the abstract divergence theorem. However, for the case Evans stated, I think it is hard to consider it via the languages of differential geometry. First of all, I assume that $dS$ means the "volume" element on $\partial U$, but $\partial U$ is not necessarily a compact Riemannian manifold here, how can we refer to its volume element?

So I guess my question should be what is the right set-up for Gauss-Green theorem with respect to $C^1$ boundaries. Is any reference?

Comment: By assumption we know $\partial U$ is an embedded $C^1$ submanifold, so it inherits a $C^0$ Riemannian metric, which is enough to define the volume measure.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I do not see any resource treating $C^0$ Riemannian metrics.

Comment: They should be considered as n-1 dimensional Hausdorff measure and they are treated very clearly in measure theory and fine properties of functions also written by Evans.